# Is this question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, topics

[How do I find the width of a car?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/44732/how-do-i-find-the-width-of-a-car) has one close vote against it for being off topic.

However I feel as it's on topic, as the dimensions of a vehicle are quite an important statistic (will it fit in my garage etc).

The [tour](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour) page does say `Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered` and the dimensions are a real question.

What do people think?

Answer (score 3):

I skipped that question in the review queue so that the community can make the call. Personally, I ask that sort of thing in the chat since there really isn't a solution to a too wide problem.